# Oracle spool location

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer to spool the DDL for some packages, but I cannot identify the location where the server is spooling. Oracle is installed on AIX, but I don't know the user it's using  to connect to the OS.

Basically, when I run:

```
spool test.lst

select 1 from dual;

spool off
```

I get a confirmation message in console

```
1                      
---------------------- 
1
```

and whenever I try to give a path, I'd get an error, probably because of user rights:

```
spool /tmp/test.lst
select 1 from dual;
spool off


Cannot create SPOOL file /tmp/test.lst 
1                      
---------------------- 
1
```

So my question is where is test.lst?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spool is a client activity, not a server one; the `.lst` file will be created on the machine that SQL Developer is on, not the server where the database it's connecting to resides.

Under Windows 7 and SQL Developer 3.1, by default for me that seems to store the `.lst` in `%APPDATA%\Sql Developer\`

You can spool to a specific directory, e.g. `spool c:\windows\temp\test.lst`, and if you have it set up can use something like `spool \\<aix-server>\<dir>\test.lst`. Paths vary according to your client OS, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Under my LINUX installation the default spool directory is from where you are running sqlplus.
ie. If you run sqlplus from a directory where you do not have write permissions it will fail.

Try typing "!" or "host" at the sqlplus prompt to goto the OS. 
pwd the directory end up in and I guess this is location of your spool.

(type exit to go back to sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

What the other guy said for the default location was true for oracle 10g but since I am using the latest oracle 21c(at the time of writing this answer) here is the solution that worked for me.

in case if you created a spool file lets say: `spool on;` `spool tempfile;`
then the default location would be at the place you installed the oracle db software which in my case is

> D:\WINDOWS.X64_213000_db_home\bin

and then in the

> bin
> folder the file would be created as
> `tempfile.LST`
> and in order to open a
> .lst
> file just use the default notepad or any such editors to open your output

> However here is a **better suggestion** by me:
> type `spool on;` `SPOOL C:/path/xyz.txt;` #here change your directory,the pathname and file name for query file
> and most importantly **DO NOT FORGET TO TYPE
> SPOOL OFF;
> at the end of the query**. In case if you forget then your file wont be created and you will lose all your progress of your saved output. and lemme give you another *pro tip:* and that is to **not write the same spoolfile name otherwise it will be overwritten**